# Luggage storage for 10 days in Tokyo

Tags: luggage-storage, tokyo

I will be starting and ending my Japan trip in Tokyo, and have some luggage that I only need at the beginning and end of my trip. The luggage is the size of a handbag.

Are there some facilities in Tokyo (preferably close to Tokyo station), where I can leave this item for around 10 days?

Neither my first, nor my second hotel want to store the item for this duration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a baggage storage area for up to 15 days at Tokyo station.

The fees:

> 420 yen/piece per day
>
> The fee increases to 840 yen/piece per day from the 6th day and beyond.

Note this space isn't cooled. You can visit the website [here.](http://www.tokyostationcity.com/en/information/locker.html)